# Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow: How do I change my email address in my user account/profile?

Tags: support, user-interface, profile-page

How do I change my Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow email address in my account/user profile?

The website layout is confusing, and lacks the normal intuitive profile where all common user data: i.e. change password, change user account email address, change info, etc.

When I select the stuff in the website tool bar, for some reason I am unable to find the place where I can edit/change profile information.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current