# Find the email that I register in my Stack Overflow

Tags: support, email

I have many emails on the same mobile number, and I have a Stack Overflow account.

I deleted Chrome and downloaded it again. All emails are gone and I can't remember what emails are on my mobile number.

And my problem is that after that I did not mention what the email address is for Stack Overflow.

And I was unable to open my Stack Overflow account.

*Note: The account I'm using to post this is a [new account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19280991/hiba-youssef) [111 reps].  My original account that I'm unable to access is [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16377085/hiba-youssef) [576 reps].*

Comment: Isn't there an existing meta question for this? On [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19280991/hiba-youssef), *"Settings"* → *"Edit Email Settings"* → *"Your Communities"* → *"Email address"*

Comment: False positives: *[Is my email address accessible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293532/is-my-email-address-accessible)* and *[How do I change the email address associated with my Stack Exchange OpenID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102392/how-do-i-change-the-email-address-associated-with-my-stack-exchange-openid)*

Comment: What is the duplicate? Candidates: *[How can I change my email address on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362969/how-can-i-change-my-email-address-on-stack-overflow)* and *[Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow: How do I change my email address in my user account/profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392783/stack-exchange-stack-overflow-how-do-i-change-my-email-address-in-my-user-acco)*.

Comment: NO, MY Question that i have stackoverflow account but i logout, then after logout i can't re-login to the account beacause i forget what is the email for the stackoverflow account

Comment: But you are logged in right now to post this(?). You should be able to see it.

Comment: this is another account

Comment: Can you [add](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/418789/edit) that information to the question? But ************************************************************************************************************************************************************ ***without*** ************************************************************************************************************************************************* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.

Comment: Considering you have no accounts that have enough reputation to get you the reputation bonus, yet you have it, I'm wondering if you deleted your [so] account and have since recreated it.

Comment: this is my account https://stackoverflow.com/users/16377085/hiba-youssef i have 600 reputation

Comment: i didin't delete my old account that have 600 reputation

Comment: So to sum it up, you have two accounts named "Hiba Youssef" and both of them have around 600 reputation points. Correct?

Comment: @Gimby I think only one account has 600 reps and rest doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want to [merge your accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts), so that all your posts (and rep!) are in one place.

Though I have never gone through this process myself, I think what happens is you provide a link to both profiles and they send an email to the address listed under each to confirm the merge. As long as you have access to the mailbox for the email you used, you'll be good to go. (And if you're still not sure which address got the email at that point, you might be able to get a hint from them. Maybe.)

I think you can have multiple emails as credentials to log into a single account, which might be helpful for you in the future.

Comment: I don't think OP has access to the email.

Comment: @TheMaster That's not entirely clear to me, but I'm pretty certain that nobody's going to give them any hints as to what email it was in public on Meta so I think this will still be the best way.

Comment: @TheMaster It *sounds* like the user has multiple e-mail addresses that forward to the same mobile number (throwaway's of a sort).  They just don't remember which one they used, since their cookie is gone on Chrome (on whatever device they are using regularly).  So hopefully, an account merge will work, since in presumably the old e-mail will still forward to the mobile.